# What is the optimal sleep schedule for bodybuilding?

Tags: bodybuilding, sleep

To find the perfect sleep schedule for bodybuilding, I think we should look at the top professional bodybuilders. 4 time Mr. Olympia [Jay Cutler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jay_Cutler_%28bodybuilder%29) said in [a Q&A session](http://www.youtube.com/my_liked_videos?feature=mh_lolz) that he gets **8-9 hours** of sleep in the off-season, but only **4 hours** while preparing for a contest. I have two questions about this style of bodybuilding sleep schedule:

1. Why does he change his hours of sleep depending on the season?
2. By sleeping 8-9 hours in the off-season, Jay Cutler is somewhere in the "long sleepers" range according to [this poster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMI9P.jpg). Is he putting on unnecessary fat as the poster says or does the poster only apply to sedentary people?

Comment: Your title asks a different question than the text of your question. Also, the FAQ suggests that "you should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."

Comment: Do you have a fitness question for yourself or just curious? Did you send him an email asking why he changes his sleep patterns?

Comment: I ask questions about Jay Cutler's sleep schedule because he is an all-star in bodybuilding and I could learn from him. He is not reachable by email. That's like emailing Micheal Jordan for basketball tips - you won't get a response.

Comment: And what works for him may not work for you. Try it and see how things go.

Comment: It's entirely possible that what he does isn't deliberate. I know I get nervous when I have a competition coming up, and I end up just not sleeping as much when that happens. It's not that I'm trying to sleep less, it's that I couldn't sleep more even if I wanted to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

References from T-nation support getting a lot of sleep.

> Get in a 9-12 hour night at least once or twice weekly. ([Things you didn't know about sleep](http://www.t-nation.com/free_online_article/sports_body_training_performance_repair/things_you_didnt_know_about_sleep_or_lack_of_it))

And how much?

> Your body knows how much sleep it needs. When it’s had enough it’ll
>   wake up on its own. ([The big sleep](http://www.t-nation.com/free_online_article/sports_body_training_performance_science/the_big_sleep_part_ii))

If you don't get enough sleep:

> performance on "real" compound lifts like bench press, squats, and deadlifts will decrease. ([The big sleep](http://www.t-nation.com/free_online_article/sports_body_training_performance_science/the_big_sleep_part_i), and [The effect of partial sleep deprivation on weight-lifting performance](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8112265))